# How can I add a method to a singleton in ExtJS4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, prototype, extjs4.1

This is the ExtJS **Shape Class**:

```
Ext.define('Ext.chart.Shape', {

    singleton: true,

    circle: function (surface, opts) {
        return surface.add(Ext.apply({
            type: 'circle',
            x: opts.x,
            y: opts.y,
            stroke: null,
            radius: opts.radius
        }, opts));
    },
    ...
});
```

I want to add a method to this Class. For example:

```
myCircle: function (surface, opts) {
        return ...
},
```

How can I do this?

Comment: 4.0.7 for now. Any differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. This is the solution if someone needs it:

```
Ext.define('MyShape', {
    override: 'Ext.chart.Shape',

    initialize: function() {
        this.callOverridden(arguments);
    },

    myCircle: function (surface, opts) {
        return ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extend to add new functions, or override to change behaviour of existing functions on a class. Links below are for the details in the sencha documentation explaining how to use them.

[Extend](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-extend)

[Override](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-override)

Sample implementation of extend:

```
Ext.define('yourCustomClassHere', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.Shape',
    newFunctionName: function () {
       //your function here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide me an example? Because I got different errors when I try to use them.

Comment: What errors? The documentation I linked to already contains examples.

Comment: I don't want to Extend it. I just want to add another method to Shape Class. And when I want to override it -Ext.chart.Shape.override({})- I got this error: "Ext.chart.Shape.override is not a function"

Comment: If I want to extend it, I got this error: "parentPrototype is undefined"

Comment: Added a sample implementation of extend. I believe Extend is for adding a new function and Override is for altering an existing functions behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Amalea for your response. I've found the solution. Maybe now I could say what I meant. Of course, I've marked your answer as useful.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question